# Batch help(open first thing in folder)

Tags: batch-file

I have a problem.
I been trying to aces a path eg.  c:\users\admin\game\
and in the game folder there are 3 folders everytime I restart the "game" the folders name changes. My question is how do I make a code that will open the 1st or 2nd .... folder without having to remodify the code to fit the name

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the name of the folder. Folder named "Halo" will come before folder named "Hello".

```
forfiles /p c:\users\admin\game /c "cmd /c if @isdir == TRUE (echo @file)"
```

You can modify this with a `for` loop.

Comment: the name of the folder is always 102XXXXXX and 103XXXXX XXXX are the random numbers that appear

Comment: So what comes first? Based on date modified or?

Comment: Wait... 102XXXXX is a folder or a file?

Comment: Then `forfiles /p PATH\102XXXXX /c "cmd /c echo @file"`

Comment: Let me try to explain again. I have a directory called C:\users\admin\game\102XXXXXX  xxxx are the random numbers that generate everytime i open the game. I need to find a way to open that folder AND acces other files and folders inside 102XXXXX  eg. C:\users\admin\game\102XXXXXX\Assets\head.png or just C:\users\admin\game\102XXXXXX\Assets

Comment: As I said in my answer *"You can modify this with a for loop."*, I'll give you an example in the answer (wait til I edit it)

Comment: also i have another question if it is not a problem for you.
I want to share this program to my friend. basicly the file i want to get is located in C:\users\%USERNAME%\socialmedia\profiles\MyProfileName
in profiles folder there is my profile nam with is eg. Ko Jumperz folder but his name is different lets say Ed smith. Can i program so that it opens the 1st folder inside the profiles folder without acctually typing his folder name?

Comment: This would take me a day to make it, becuz I'm currently having troubles with it